# Implementing "Learn More" balloon on HTML text/links

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What would be the best way to have the user to hover over a link/label/text and get a quick learn more balloon popping up which would contain information about that item.  Is there anything native to HTML5?  I've looked through w3schools and a few other sources on the web but couldn't spot anything useful.

Comment: This is a very broad question .. I'm also not sure about *best* way.  What are your goals?

Comment: I have some form questionnaire.  Want to have a "Learn More" link in front of some question which would give extra information about that particular question as in a balloon, without have to open any extra tabs or windows or anything chunky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For short, simple text, setting the 'title' attribute of the dom node works well with most browsers.

If you want more complex content, say, html-formatted content, qtip2 - http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip2/ is a nice jQuery plugin for that.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need html5 to do help hover bubbles.  You also don't need javascript.  Just use CSS:  http://csstooltip.com/

Comment: Even though this is a very interesting concept, however, I didn't end up using this method since I didn't have much time to find out how this works as there were no documentation on this page as how this is meant to be applied on a page.  Since I'm new to CSS, would you be kind enough to let me know how this is used as my personal knowledge?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) in twitter bootstrap.

Comment: I tried this but it would be extremely difficult is you would want to use this over pre-existing CSS.  But this is definitely a useful answer when employing bootstrap CSS on a fresh website.